# How to create a Scheduled Task programatically in C/C++?

Tags: c, windows, scheduled-tasks

I created a small application which makes some settings. I want to start this application before a user logs into windows. Unfortunately i didn't find any solution for this problem, so i thought i could create a scheduled task. Unfortunately i didn't find any solution neither for this. So my question is, that could somebody help me? I would appropritiate any help, idees, or examples. Basicly my question is, how can i start an application before a user logs into windows? It is necessary to mention that i need to this on Windows XP!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Task Scheduler API.

[Creating a Task Using NewWorkItem Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446826%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) seems to be what you are describing here.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please summarize the referenced documentation in your answer.

Answer (score -3):

[Link to the below thread](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/run-program-befor-login/134899.html)

> You can do this in Windows XP Pro..
>
> "Start" "Run" type gpedit.msc
>
> Under "Computer Configuration"
>   "Windows Settings" Double click
>   "Scripts(Startup/Shutdown)" Double
>   click "Startup" in right pane. Click
>   "Add" button and browse to your
>   program and then click "ok" then Click
>   "Ok" again.
>
> you can now exit out of all the Group
>   Policy editor..
>
> Now when Windows XP Pro boots up.
>   before the user logs on this program
>   will run for you.

Comment: Yes, basicly that's what i want, but i need to this programatically, not manually.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying you want the program you write to make it self run before authentication? Because that should solve your problem, or maybe i am just misunderstanding you.

Comment: Basicly yes. My program should start automatically before anyone presses "CTRL+ALT+DEL" and logs into the computer.It's very complicated. My program will run(but only one time) before anyone logs in,and then restarts the computer. After a restart my program wont run again, so it should create another scheduled task to run again,so i need to create a scheduled task programatically, not manually.

Comment: I see. Sorry i am not familiar enough with windows to further assist.